# How do I get my HTML button call my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button

So I've been working for a long time on researching how to fix this problem but nothing is working. My problem is that I am trying to make a button in HTML and use it to call my function in my javascript but every time I get an error or nothing happens.

this is the code I've been trying

HTML:

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">



      </script>
      <button onclick= "test1"> test</button>
    </html>
```

Javascript:

```
    onEvent("test1", "click", function( ) {
      console.log("message");
    });


    console.log ("test");
```

Comment: `test1` is a function?

Comment: well I'm just trying to get the button to work right now

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense. On click, you're trying to execute `test1` which is... zero? Then, `onEvent` is not defined (it's not a native Javascript function). Check your console, what does it say?

Comment: It could help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

Comment: ...and also this : [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event)

Comment: Your `onclick` attribute must reference a function-typed variable. And check how event handlers work with the link that @Jeremu Thille give you.

Comment: Why should it work ? There is no test1 defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an onclick attribute with a function:

```js
function test1() {
  console.log('message');
}
```

```html
<button onclick= "test1()"> test</button>
```

Or dynamically add an event listener:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
console.log('message');
});
```

```html
<button id="button"> test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that using multiple ways:

The most obvious solution will be writing an `onclick` attribute in your button element.

```
<button onclick="FunctionCall()">Click me</button>
```

or other method is to add event listener to the button

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("Button Clicked");
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Button</button>
```

Also check the jsfiddle link for working: https://jsfiddle.net/tkfbg0dw/4/

let me know, if you need any help. Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow also has built-in snippets, that I took the liberty to do with your code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function testFunction(){
  console.log('Hello World')
}
```

```html
<button onclick="testFunction()">Click here</button>
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank You!